# Delete Duplicated Rows IN SQLITE using XCODE

Tags: xcode, sqlite, uitableview

I am currently using Xcode to create and edit a SQLITE document.

Currently i use the following syntax to input and delete duplicates in the database using didselectrowatindex in the uitableview . But it dosnt seem to be working.

```
NSString *sql = @"INSERT INTO RECENT ('NAME', 'TITLE', 'VIDEO', 'IMAGE', 'DESCRIPTION' ) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?);delete from RECENT where rowid not in (select max(rowid) from RECENT group by 'IMAGE');";`
```

what im trying to achieve is to add data to a sqlite database. If the data is already on the database then to delete this row and t ensuring that the most recent sits at the top of a uitableview.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem simpler to use this SQL instead:

```
INSERT OR REPLACE
INTO recent (name, title, video, image, description)
VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)
```

Of course, that will only work with a suitable `UNIQUE` constraint (on the `image` column I'd suggest, based on the code you were using before).

Comment: This is exactly the way i should go. Thank you so much @Donal Fellows